# Suppress JInput Warnings

Tags: java, jinput

My JInput code works fine, it just prints these warnings to the console every time the program starts. I need to suppress them.

Nov 29, 2017 8:59:55 AM net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment getControllers
WARNING: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 10
Nov 29, 2017 8:59:55 AM net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment getControllers
WARNING: Attempting to use default windows plug-in.

EDIT: I found a way to do it, but it's a bit of a hack: `System.err.close();` Is there a way for me to temporarily disable `System.err` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `System.setErr()`:

```
    PrintStream error=System.err;
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream(){
        public void write(int a){}
    }));
    controllers=ControllerEnvironment.getDefaultEnvironment().getControllers();
    System.setErr(error);
```